# How to update a php variable inside a variable

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$var1 = 'Hello';
$var2 = $var1.' friend';
```

Inside the if statement, if submit is clicked, I want to update var1 to 'Hi' so I am expecting 'Hi friend' as output. But it was not working- 'Hello friend' is still the output. I want to call it via var2. How can var1 be updated which is in var2?

Here is my full code:

```
<?php 
$var1 = 'Hello';
$var2 = $var1.' friend';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $var1 = 'Hi';
    echo $var2;

} else{ 
echo '<form method="post" action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br> </form>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: you must repeat the code  ..   $var1 = 'Hi';     echo $var1 . $var2;  once you have assigned $var1.' friend'; to $var2  .. the value is fixed  (assigned ) to $var2  .. and if you want a new one you must reassign

Comment: Maybe you should use a function for that. You can't do it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won't work, you have a miss conception of how things function. `$var2 = $var1.' friend';` will assign a *value* immediately to ??$var2??, not a formular or something evaluated later. So `$var2` contains whatever `$var1` holds at the time of the assignment.

What you are looking for is a *function*:

```
<?php 

function greetWithPhrase($phrase) {
  return $phrase . ' friend';
}

$var1 = 'Hello';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $var1 = 'Hi';
    echo greetWithPhrase($var1);    
} else{ 
  echo '<form method="post" action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'">
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br> </form>';
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. Im new to php, coming from a   java background :P